# error sqoop No manager for connect string

Tags: sqoop

i want to list all my databases with sqoop so i use this command:

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:as400://url/Pzed9 --username zed --password as400
```

But i got this error :

```
 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string:
```

I checked the link many times and it's not wrong, so what do you think is my problem?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `–driver com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver` as part of `Sqoop` command.

Comment: I'm using list-databases syntax which is only working with HSQLDB, MySQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches for getting all the databases using sqoop invocation.

1. use `--driver` connection depending on your jdbc connection.
   e-g, `–driver com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver`
2. is to specify the connection manager (manually) if it is not getting automatically. using `--connection-manager`.
   e-g `--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager`
   hope it helps!